# Razor injecting code from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a razor snippet stored in a string:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
```

I store the code snippet in my cache. How can I inject the string such that it renders as if it was part of the original view file, executing the code also?

I have tried:

```
@ApplicationCache.GetDynamicString("MyString")
@Html.Raw(ApplicationCache.GetDynamicString("MyString"))
```

These methods return a string, not an MvcHtmlString. I could dynamically write to a partial view from my server and render the partial view, but I'm wondering if there's a helper I'm missing.

Comment: this is actually a very good question

Comment: Why not try to build a helper to do that?

Comment: Weird. I would have thought `Html.Raw` would have worked. What about doing `@MvcHtmlString.Create(ApplicationCache.GetDynamicString("MyString"))`?

Comment: Agree with @DavidSherret. MvcHtmlString.Create() should work for you

Comment: It seems like you've got a Catch-22 situation here. The `Raw` call injects the string into the View, but the Razor rendering engine never gets a chance to parse and execute it because it's already past that point.  You'd almost need a multi-pass parser of the Razor view, the first pass allowing you to inject new code into the view and the second pass to then parse and execute that new code.

Comment: I agree this is a catch-22. I think I will have to go with writing to a partial view file in the background. To the others commenting on Html.Raw, that won't execute any c# code. It just outputs that as plain-text.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall: Use RazorEngine from my proposed duplicate. That *is* able to render the 'view in code'.

Comment: Are you essentially trying to compile partial view from string? (Patrrick Hofman's suggestion is possible approach in this case).

Comment: Oh... I assumed the code to execute was JavaScript and not C#.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I guess it depends on whether it's important to maintain the current view context and/or model metadata. I'd be interested in seeing a solution that assumes it is.

Comment: @AntP: I agree, but that is not clear from the context. I would be happy to reopen if OP tells it *is* necessary.

Comment: I solved this by using razor engine as highlighted by Patrick Hofman. I pass the Request.Authenticated value to a helper which builds a model from the value, injecting it into my string template, and renders it back out.

Comment: @DavidJamesBall: Glad you fixed it. If you want an answer on the part Ant P put here, you might want to edit your question and I will reopen. If not, let's keep it this way.